# What word describes things that are similar yet different?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, antonyms

There are two words on either side of the word I'm looking for: *synonym* and *antonym.* Of course, a synonym is a word that means the same thing (automobile vs. vehicle), and an antonym is a word that means the opposite (male vs. female). However, let's use the example of automobiles. There are different types: car, truck, van, SUV, etc. They're neither synonyms or antonyms of each other. But is there a word that describes their similarities, given they're all automobiles?

The word should fit this sentence:

> A car is a _______________ of a truck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case you've described truck, van etc. would be [hyponyms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyponym) of automobile. American OED defines [hyponym](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hyponym):

> a word of more specific meaning than a general or superordinate term
>   applicable to it. For example, spoon is a hyponym of cutlery.
>   Contrasted with [hypernym](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hypernym).

Automobile, then, would be a [*hypernym*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hypernym) for truck.

> a word with a broad meaning that more specific words fall under; a
>   superordinate. For example, color is a hypernym of red.

Comment: Yes, but here the OP is asking how two hyponyms of the same hypernym relate *to each other*.

Comment: Actually I didn't realize there were two similar words describing the two different pieces to this scenario. What I was looking for was the word which can fit "The word Car is a ___ of a Truck".

Comment: @JerryDodge ah I get it now...